# C# How to filtered datatable rows which containing alphanumeric with special characters using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have below data in my C# Datatable

[image]

What I want is to filter those data which has Alphanumeric with special characters like:

`HOAUD039#`
`HOAUD00$`

So I try below regex in my linq query:

```
var matches =
    dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => Regex.IsMatch(row["Empolyee_CRC"].ToString(),
                                "^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"]*$"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

which returns me both Alphanumeric result and Alphanumeric with characters like below:

[image]

Now my question is simple and clear what is the right way to show results only having Alphanumeric with special characters.

I've also tried this regex but it is also not work
`^(?:[\d,\/().]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d,\/().]*)?$`

Comment: your special character always to be at last ?

Comment: what if I say may be yes or may be it is in between or may be it is on start.

Comment: check answer. i think i have covered all the cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this based on your example patterns this will serve**

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[!@#$&()\\-`.+,\/\"]).*$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `(?=.*\d)` - Condition for checking at least one digit must be there in match.
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` - Condition for checking at least one character must be there in match.
- `(?=.*[!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"])` - Condition for checking at least one special must be there in match.
- `.*`  - Match anything except newline.
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xWquhV/8)

Comment: The forth bird provide its answer in c# thats why I accepted it. Thanks for your time. I upvote your answer as I know there is no need to downvote your answer.

Comment: But are these are not included in special characters ?

Comment: @Ahmer was just curious to know if I missed something thats it. It doesn't matter vpvote or down vote I am here just to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

In your regex you are using a single chararacter class which will only select one out of many, but your have 3 requirements.

In your second regex, everything is optional due to the `*` and the `?`

You could use 3 positive lookaheads to assert your requirements:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$&()`.+,\/\-])(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Z\d!@#$&()`.+,\/\-]+$
```

In C#:

```
string pattern = @"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$&()`.+,\/\-])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$&()`.+,\/-]+$";
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.*\d)` Assert a digit
- `(?=.*[!@#$&()`.+,/-])` Assert a special character
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` Assert a lowercase or uppercase character
- `[A-Za-z\d!@#$&()`.+,/-]+` Match 1+ times only the allowed characters
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKuWnC/1) | [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/2QpNqT)

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan my regex was same only. i don't see any difference ?

Comment: @CodeManiac The question of the OP is to match  Alphanumeric with special characters. The solution you posted also matches [A1@ÃƒÆ](https://regex101.com/r/IuUGnS/1). Note that `[A-z]` matches more than `[A-Za-z]`